# Which is the preferred way to implement authorization and authentication in my gwt/osgi web application?

Tags: java, authentication, gwt, authorization, osgi

Im developing a web application with gwt and osgi (equinox).
The application is running on a jetty.

Now I need to do some authentication (simple username/pwd login and oauth)
and some authorization (e.g. check access rights on specific java objects, i don't need access control on url patterns).
I also want to be able to save user preferences and store user comments.

I already looked at (including downloading and testing demo applications from tutorials)

- [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/index.html)
- [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/)
- How to do my own solution (Using e.g. [Scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java) for OAuth)

But I'm still not sure which is the better way to do it.
Spring looks quite complex and might be a lot overhead. 
Shiro isn't able to do OAuth (can i add OAuth using Scribe?).
What do I really win using those frameworks? And how well do they work together with gwt and osgi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested spring security as well as shiro. Honestly I do not like both. Some time ago we discussed on the Apache Karaf mailing list how to do role based access control. They both reinvent security in their own proprietary ways.

I first brought up Shiro myself but after a few tests it was not too compelling for non web usage. We also dismissed Spring Security because of its complexity and spring dependency. In the end we settled to use plain JAAS.

So basically you have some kind of authentication that does a JAAS login and then use the logged in user with the code below for authorization:

```
AccessControlContext acc = AccessController.getContext();
Subject subject = Subject.getSubject(acc);
Set<Principal> principals = subject.getPrincipals();
```

This allows you to create a very standards based authentication / authorization system while introducing no additional libs.

Based on this David Bosschaert created role based access control for OSGi services:
http://coderthoughts.blogspot.fr/2013/10/jmx-role-based-access-control-for-karaf.html

I am not sure if you can use the karaf implementation directly but it might give you some ideas how to create your own system. In the long term I hope security libs stop reinventing java security and instead use jaas at their core but no idea if that actually will happen.

Comment: I really appreciate your attempt to help me but what you're trying to tell me is: 
- I shouldn't use shiro or spring security, because you don't like it for non web usage, but I do have a web application and not liking something is not a reason
- why should i use JAAS when i want to have oauth?
- you're throwing in one line of code that doesn't really help
- the link you have posted explains some karaf specific stuff, which doesn't help either
if I understood something wrong correct me, but the way I understand this doesn't really help me with my decision

Comment: Oauth is great for the interaction between client and your server. I meant to use jaas to track the login and do authorization inside your process. Of course you have to use something like oauth to communicate with the outside world. The idea is to just do a jaas login or even just a priveledged action call with the data from oauth to track that the user is authorized. In this case using jaas inside your application makes sure that your choice of oauth is encapsulated and does not directly affect how you do authorization later.

Comment: Looks like SAP uses such a combination of oauth and jaas. http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Img/How+To+Implement+OAuth+Signed+Fetch+Services+and+Modules

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using Spring security in my OSGI application. however the beauty of spring security is you could always extend the functionality and use Shiro in Spring environment.

possible advantages of Spring Security :

1. Spring Security support for [OAuth](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth) and [Kerberos](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/extensions.html)
2. Active Development , very large community
3. Support for Apache Shiro.

On the other hand Apache Shiro

1. Does not support [OAuth](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth) or [Kerberos](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/extensions.html).
2. Compared to Spring Security, not much active development.
3. Not so complex , easier to learn and implement.

At the end of the day, it depends on which of these two make more sense to you. For Shiro integration with Spring take a [look](http://shiro.apache.org/spring.html)

Comment: You're answer is helpful, but it only looks at a part of my question:
 - is an own solution viable?

and why would I use Spring Security and Shiro?

Answer (score 0):

I would not go your own route. It gets very complicated quickly and you likely will miss bit security gotchas that have been solved several times over in these bigger frameworks. Take the time to read the docs and learn the frameworks.

I have been implementing a custom authentication protocol (don't ask why) for some apps where I work. It needed to support multiple frameworks and do method-level security like you have to. Like Ashish, I found Shiro to be lacking for the same reasons as he cites. This left me with Spring Security, JAAS, or a custom filter.

Spring Security is complex, but once you grok the API, your implementation will not be as complex. Spring Security is a great set of building blocks to build upon. Once you know the interfaces you need to leverage, doing things like method-level security is pretty easy. And it supports multiple authentication schemes like OAuth2, basic auth, etc.. JAAS is a pain in the ass and not as portable between containers. There's still some Jetty-specific and Tomcat-specific bits you have to deal with. Spring Security is portable between containers and works great with Spring Boot.